# Invalid Relation Operator when passing List in Where Clause

Tags: oracle

I have the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1 TD
WHERE COL1 like '%' ||?|| '%'
AND COL2 like '%' ||?|| '%'
AND ((:statusId) IS NULL) OR ((:statusId) IS NOT NULL AND STATUS_ID IN (:statusId)))
ORDER BY COL1 DESC;
```

StatusId can have multiple values/single value or null. When i pass the value 1,2 using Spring JDBC i get invalid relation operator.

Comment: You are using the same parameter name,`statusId`, everywhere.  It can't possibly be a list and a scalar at the same time.

Comment: That's because you are not passing in 1, 2 (a list of two numbers separated by comma); you are passing in a string enclosed in single quotes, like '1, 2'. That's not the same thing, and there's a way around it, but not a trivial one. This question has been asked a thousand times on SO, search for "variable IN list" or similar.

Comment: @mathguy It is true that one can't pass a list.  If it is a string that is passed  that the query will not return the rows th OP will expect. But if :statusId is a string why should this raise an error?

Comment: @miracle173 - I don't know about the specific error the OP reported; but this WOULD definitely have to raise an error, if the condition is for a number (`status_id`) to be `IN` a list consisting of one member, which is a *string* which can't be converted to a number. In plain SQL he should get the "invalid number" error.

Comment: @mathguy I think if the string couldn't be converted to a number then some conversion error would be raised.

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing `1,2` without apostrophe then the problem is `(:statusId) IS NULL` and `(:statusId) IS NOT NULL`

If you're passing `'1,2'` then you'll have issues at `STATUS_ID IN (:statusId)` cause it will only equal when STATUS_ID = '1,2' and not when STATUS_ID = 1 or STATUS_ID = 2.

Taking all of the above into consideration you should pass it with apostrophe and remove them from the last bit `STATUS_ID IN (REPLACE(:statusId,'''',''))`